# How to pull data from associative models in active model serializes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, active-model-serializers

I'm using `active_model_serializers` gem to send response as `JSON`.
I pull the data from association models but how to get only those data from `questions` table where `UserType` equals to `clients.UserType`.

`ClientSerializer`:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :username, :access_token, :UserType

  has_many :questions, include: :all
end
```

and `QuestionSerializer`:

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :question, :client_id, :UserType
  belongs_to :user
end
```

here is the output as `JSON`:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "username": "171fdkjgku",
    "access_token": "77NVccAJG7hEKSGQUcKkSip5",
    "UserType": 1,
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "question": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "client_id": 4,
            "UserType": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "question": "Lorem Ipsum 2",
            "client_id": 4,
            "UserType": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "question": "Lorem Ipsum 3",
            "client_id": 4,
            "UserType": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output `JSON`:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "username": "171fdkjgku",
    "access_token": "77NVccAJG7hEKSGQUcKkSip5",
    "UserType": 1,
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "question": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "client_id": 4,
            "UserType": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "question": "Lorem Ipsum 3",
            "client_id": 4,
            "UserType": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining the `questions` method yourself and fetch scoped questions in it:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :username, :access_token, :UserType, :questions

  def questions
    ques = self.object.questions.where(UserType: self.object.UserType).to_a
    ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(ques, each_serializer: QuestionSerializer).as_json
  end
end
```